# Как поместить кнопки в массив?

Tags: c#, массивы

Помогите поместить кнопки, в C#, в массив. Буду рад если поможете!

Answer (score 3):

**Точно так же, как и обычный простой тип:**

```
Button[] btns = new Button[2];
btns[0] = button1;  // помещаем в массив уже созданную кнопку( размещенную на форме )
MessageBox.Show(btns[0].Text); // смотрим, действительно ли это так...
btns[0].Text = "Some1";
btns[1] = new Button();
btns[1].Text = "Some2";
```

**UPD:**

Вот я написал для вас небольшой примерчик, исходя из которого вы должны будете сами реализовать необходимую вам логику:

```
            List<Button> btns = new List<Button>();
            foreach (object o in Form1.ActiveForm.Controls)
            {
                if ((o as Button) is Button) btns.Add((o as Button));
            }

            Random rand = new Random();
            int c = rand.Next(0,btns.Count);

            btns[c].Text = "X";
```

Comment: @Asen а я щас хочу по рандому присвоить одному из 4-х кнопок название. Как это сделать? Просто ты тут конкретно указал их названия, а я там знать не буду, к какому из 4-х присвоить одно название. Поможешь разобраться?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Вы хотите присваивать рандомные кэпшны для кнопок или что?

Comment: @Asen у меня 5 кнопок, с пустым текстом. При нажатии на любую, туда, в текст кнопки, записывается "А". Остается 4 кнопок у меня. И после того, как я нажал, получил "А", автоматически хочу, чтобы текст одной из оставшихся 4-х кнопок, по рандому, изменился на "Б"!

Comment: Смотрите апдейт.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую!

Comment: Вы, как я думаю, понимаете, что все это дело было "по-бырому" мною реализовано "на коленке" лишь в качестве примера для вас.